# Scan with Regexp.Union how to use variables with options in union \b \ix?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace hard coded `regex.union` values for one that I read from a file. I cannot make it work let us say for `\b` word boundary. At the bottom of my example, I have good case, and I see that `regex1` and `regex2` are different. How can I attach that special `?-mix:` and make `\b` and `/ix` working?

```
   s = '/*  aaa SElect /*   selectXXX  ZZZ_Select '

   puts '--------------------  1  no results here'
RegexData = ['/*', 'select']             # this arrage got values from file
puts 'Regexdata ' + RegexData[0].chomp + '    ' + RegexData[1].chomp  

regex1 = Regexp.union(RegexData[0].chomp , RegexData[1].chomp)       #add ALL elements from RegexData???
puts  'r1             ' +regex1.to_s
puts  'scan1 ' + s.scan(regex1).to_s

puts '--------------------  2 works OK for test '
regex2 = Regexp.union(/\/\*/,/\bselect\b/ix,/myTable/)
puts 'r2              ' + regex2.to_s
#(?-mix:(?-mix:\/\*)|(?ix-m:\bselect\b)|(?-mix:myTable))
puts  'scan2 ' + s.scan(regex2).to_s
```

Comment: How i get -1 on my question, can anybody help, what is wrong with it ?

Comment: It's done with all guidelines and homework done

Comment: I see that those \b, /ix should be added in regexp.Union statement but none of resources state that it's available if using variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me this way you can pass variable into regex, syntax is pretty complex but it works!! with feeding all arrays element into Union c'be more complex if option are different for each element. Note usage of # and curly brackets.

```
s = ' select /*  aaa Select /*   SElectXXX  ZZZ_SelecT '
regex1 = '\bselect\b'            # | /\bselect\b/ix|(?-mix:myTable))'
regex2 = '\/\*'              
puts  'scan1 ' + s.scan(/#{regex1}/ix).to_s
```

Nice question, nothing wrong, all inclusive. Good luck!
More good tricks is here
[enter link description here](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/useful-lesser-known-ruby-regexp-methods/)

and it also work for Union, but note it's not parsing elements of array, just fixed number of elements, in this case =2.

```
regu = Regexp.union(/#{regex2}/, /#{regex1}/ix)
puts  'scanUN ' + s.scan(regu).to_s
#scanUN ["select", "/*", "Select", "/*"]
```

Comment: @Mich28 SO itself gives the right to edit questions and answers to people with certain badges. I saw the revision history and there is nothing wrong in Sawa's edit.